# Batch insert with Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to insert 800 changesets using a multirow INSERT query with Ecto. I'm using postgres. I see that postgrex supports this now. Is it possible yet with Ecto?

I'm also open to doing this via prepared statement if that's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ecto 2.0 will support [`Repo.insert_all/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/f23688e6ce94c97519bac14eaf0c36e99e0f205e/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L414-L440) (current latest version is 2.0.0-rc.4 which supports this), but it doesn't support inserting changesets, only raw Maps or Keyword lists, so you'll have to filter all valid changesets and extract the fields from them yourself like you would have needed to if you used the Postgrex bulk insert feature.

Comment: Thanks! As a side note, this is a more direct way to access the DB and doesn't offer most of the conveniences of `insert`, such as generating timestamps.

Comment: Note that you might run into limits for big inserts (e.g. `postgresql protocol can not handle 84104 parameters, the maximum is 65535`)